# Adapting Eclipse keys to Mac osx

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse on OSX. For some shortcuts I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and some <kbd>CMD</kbd>.

Example: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for opening type but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for call hierarchy.

Is there a scheme for Mac with less distribution of shortcut keys?